# vue.js: change the values of a table in a reactive way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, state, vuetify.js

To create a table I am using `vuetify` `data-table`. The data is coming from an `express` server which is requested via `axios` and then gives me a response that is structured as follows:

```
[
    {
        datetime: 123456789,
        order: "abc100",
        status: "ok"
    },
    {
        datetime: 123456789,
        order: "abc200",
        status: "ok"
    },
    ...
]
```

This response is being used by the vue front as follows:

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="orders"
>
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td >{{ props.item.order }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.datetime }}</td>
        <td >{{ props.item.status }}</td>
    </template>
</v-data-table>    


data () {
    return {
        headers: [
            { ... },
            { ... },
            ...
        ],
        orders: []
    }
},

created () {
    QueryService.orders().then(response => this.orders = response.data)       
}
```

I know that I can change the state via `this.orders` now without reloading the whole site, but how can I access the individual rows? They are in the array, so how can I add a new one or change an already existing one if I have 1000 orders? its hard to guess them via an index.

**EDIT:**

I can't update the data-table via `this.orders = response.data` and I don't know why. The code itself works and I can test via console.log, that `this.data` is being changed, but the data-table is not being updated!

```
created () {
    setInterval(function() { 
        QueryService.orders().then(response => this.orders = response.data)
    }, 15000)
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I figured out that `this.orders` which is assigned inside `QueryService` is not the same `orders` as the one inside `data ()`, but I still don't know how to access `orders` inside `data ()`. I tried `this.$data.orders`, but it doesn't work either. Anybody has an idea?

Comment: You haven't specified where `vue-data-table` comes from, but assuming you're using the Vuetify one, the docs would indicate that when you are correctly scoping `:items="orders"` and `props.item.foo` is the right place to find `foo`.  Have you tried using mock data and updating it manually (EG with a button click) to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `this` the right way, because of the scope inside the function. Just define another variable before the function and you can access `data()` properties.

```
pollData: function () {

    var vm = this;

    setInterval(function() {
        ContractQueryService.orders().then(response => vm.orders = response.data)
    }, 5000)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to update an array at an index in a reactive way to is to `vm.$set(arr, index, value)`  See this Vue doc [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

To find your order, you could search the orders array with [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).  Really, 1000 items is not that many, especially when they're loaded into memory already.  It's not optimal, but it should be pretty fast.  If you plan to do a lot of searching you might want to maintain an index separately, perhaps in the Vuex store.

```
// searching for an order by its `order` property.
const targetIndex = this.orders.findIndex(entry => entry.order=orderId)
this.$set(this.orders, targetIndex, modifiedOrder)
```

EDIT: updated for Vue2 syntax.